# Share declaration of cython's extension type which is a member data of another extension type

Tags: python, cython

I want to share the declaration of one class which is the *member data* of another class in cython using the [share of declaration for extension types](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/sharing_declarations.html#sharing-extension-types).

#### Example of code:

This is the python wrapper (`run.py`) that is run by user. It declares a `Solver` class.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# filename: run.py 

import Solver

S = Solver.Solver()
Result = S.Solve()
```

The `Solver` object has a `cpdef Solve()` member function which is called once from the python part of the code. The `Solver` class has `cdef object Computation` member data:

```
# filename: Solver.pyx

from Computation cimport Computation
cdef class Solver:
    cdef object Comp

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.Comp = Computation()

    cpdef double Solve(self):
        Result =  self.Comp.Add(4)
        return Result
```

The `Computation` class is merely a cython code:

```
# filename: Computation.pxd

cdef class Computation:
    cdef int a
    cdef double Add(self,double b)
```

and

```
# filename: Computation.pyx

cdef class Computation:
    def __cinit__(self):
        self.a = 3

    cdef double Add(self,double b):
        return self.a + b
```

The `setup.py` is:

```
# filename: setup.py

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
        package_data = {"Computation": ["Computation.pxd"]},
        ext_modules = cythonize(["*.pyx"],include_path=["."]),
)
```

`Solver.Solve()` calls `Computation.Add()` many times, but here I suppressed the `for` loops for simplicity. The point is that calling `Add()` should have the minimal cost, hence I have declared it with `cdef`.

#### The problem:

All files are in the same directory. I compile with `python setup build_ext --inplace`. Then by running `./run` I receive the following error:

```
Exception AttributeError: "'Computation.Computation' object has no attribute 'Add'" in 'Solver.Solver.Solve' ignored
```

I have two ways to get around with this:

1. If I change `Add()` from a `cdef` to a `cpdef` function I no longer get this error. But in this case, the `Solve()` calls a `cpdef` which has an overhead compared to `cdef`. I want to avoid using `cpdef` for `Add()`, since in the actual code, `Add()` is an expensive code and is called may times.
2. If in the `Solver` class, I do not declare `Comp` object as a **member data**, rather just declare it inside the `Solve()` function, I do not get this error. Something like this:

   ```
   # filename: Solver.pyx

   from Computation cimport Computation
   cdef class Solver:
       # No member data here.
       cpdef double Solve(self):
           # We declare Comp here instead:
           Comp = Computation()
           Result =  Comp.Add(4)
           return Result
   ```

But I prefer the `Comp` to be a member of `Solver` as well. My guess is that by declaring `Comp` in a python code `def __cinit__(self)`, the `cdef` functions are not declared anymore.

So, my question is that how can I share declaration of an extension type which itself is a member data of another class? That is, how a cython extension type can be declared in `__cinit__()`?

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself. Simply in `Solver.pyx` the line

```
cdef object Comp
```

should be changed to

```
cdef Computation Comp
```

which here the object is explicitly typed. 
With this the extension type's `cdef` method can be accessed elsewhere.